# Buck converter (MAX5035D) regulation problem

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I didn´t expect to be having issues with a buck converter, but here I am.
My design goal is a simple 15-60 V to 10 V buck converter. I settled with the following schmematic:

[image: schematic]

I designed a 2-layer board with copper pours on both layers with stitching vias:

[image: KiCad layout]

(Ignore the terrible soldering)

[image: actual PCB]

During testing, I made temporary changes to component values:
Input capacitance: 11 μF,
Output capacitance: 10 μF,
Feedback resistors: 9.1 kΩ and 1.3 kΩ

I tested the converter with an input voltage of 25 V from a fairly noisy bench supply. I loaded the 10 V rail with 120 Ω. Here are the results:

"DC" results:
Vout = 5.05 V instead of ~10 V, Vfb = 0.63 V instead of ~1.22 V according to the datasheet.

"AC" results (with bad oscilloscope probing):

[image: input ripple measured at the input capacitors (AC-coupled)]

Data measured after changing inductor from 22 μF to 100 μF:
[image: Vout = f(Rload), parameter: Vin]

Weird switch node voltage:

[image: switch node voltage (DC-coupled)]

I know that the layout and component selection is not optimal, but I think this should only explain high ripple, low efficiency, etc. but not such a massive regulation issue.

Datasheets:
[Diode](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mbrs1100t3-d.pdf)
[MAX5035](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max5035.pdf)

Comment: What convinces you that the inductor you chose is suitable? Data sheet please.

Comment: @Andyaka My component selection is highly dependend on what I have available, since shipping takes quite a while or is very expensive. The inductor is a Murata LQH32DN220K53 (0.7Ohms, rated for 250mA, SRF 19MHz). It is undersized for my application but should be fine with the 120 Ohm load which should draw 83mA @ 10V. Link: (https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail?partno=LQH32DN220K53%23)

Comment: Component selection should be based on what is needed and not what you have available. If you can't do that then you can't expect to take current peaks into your inductor that are bigger than what it's rated at without the obvious problems of failing to meet expectations. Just calculate the peak inductor current in your problematic scenario.

Comment: You are right, I totally neglected the current ripple. The inductor leads to a peak-to-peak current delta of at least around 2 A at a fsw = 125 kHz and Vin - Vout = 15 V. I replaced it with a 100 uH inductor rated for ~ 1 A, which should reduce the delta to 500 mA. The circuit behaviour remained similar, the output voltage dropped even lower to 3.6 V.

Comment: Well, it's still feeling like an inductor problem to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. Might play around with the inductor a bit. What confuses me, is that the switch node voltage never even comes close to the input voltage. During the on time of the internal high side switch the switch node voltage should be close to 25V, right?

Comment: Maybe your input power supply is struggling. Maybe it is current limited and cannot sustain the 25 volts?

Comment: It is noisy but can do at least 100W, current limiting was also not active. There are local decoupling caps at the input of the buck converter. I have also switched the MAX5035 in case it was faulty. I feel like either  something is broken or there is a massive error in this design.

Comment: Maybe start with a light load and progressively add more load current and see what point it begins to stop performing as a voltage regulator. Try this on a range of input supply voltages.

Comment: I added a graph that shows 3 different loads for 3 different input voltages.

Comment: Try and measure VD and BST-to-Lx. Should be around 8V and 7V.

Comment: The graph slopes look quite disappointing @fakulol

Comment: @Andyaka Meaning that you were hoping for more data or that the result itself is not "good news"?

Comment: The regulation is poor and I can't tell you how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ideas on the matter:

The inductor value is too small. The equation calls for 44uH at least

> vin=[15 25 31]; vout = 10
> ((vin-vout).*vout./vin)/(0.3*2*125e3)
> ans =
> 4.4444e-05   8.0000e-05   9.0323e-05

Counter intuitively a lower current needs a higher minimum inductor, so you might be able to put a higher load and get better results.

Not having the feedback at the right point has been a problem for me in the past. One problem is the FB point will see a smoothed version of the inductor switching and may not switch at the right time.

But before you take the effort to do switch the wire, make a differential measurement (with a diff probe at pin2 of the inductor and pin 1 of the C10 pad) if you see a difference more than a few mV than that could be the problem.

[image]

Comment: I continued testing with 100 uH, forgot to update the question. Changing the feedback point is probably a good idea, might investigate.